# Exact height of \hbox

Tags: boxes, height

I have problems controlling the exact height of an `\hbox`; what is wrong with this example?

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\mybox}[2]{
\fbox{ \vbox to #1cm{
       \vfil\hbox to 1cm {\hfill #2 \hfill}
       \vfil}}}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\arraycolsep}{-0.1pt}
$$\begin{array}{cc}
\mybox{2}{a} & 
\begin{array}[b]{c}
\mybox{1}{b}\\[-0.65pt]
\mybox{1}{c}
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

\end{document}
```

I expected the total height of the two boxes on the right to be the same as the height of the left box, namely 2cm. However, there seem to be a hidden height which is added. How can I control this?

---

#### Update

Thanks for the quick and detailed replies, it helped a lot!

However, there is still another problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\mylenA
\newlength\mylenB


\newcommand{\myarray}[4][t]{
    \renewcommand{\arraycolsep}{-#3pt}
    \begin{array}[#1]{#2}#4\end{array}}

\newcommand\mybox[4][t]{%
    \setlength\mylenA{#3ex-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}%
    \setlength\mylenB{#3ex-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}%
    \fcolorbox{black}{#2}{\parbox[#1][\mylenA][c]{\mylenB}{\centering #4}}}

\begin{document}

\[\left(
\myarray{ll}{0.1}{

\myarray{ll}{0.15}{
   \mybox{yellow}{4}{A}&\mybox{green}{4}{B}\\[-5.15pt]
 & \mybox{blue}{4}{C}
}
& \mybox{red}{8}{D}
}
\right)\]

\end{document}
```

The left and right brackets are way to large; does anyone see what goes wrong?

And, second, is there a more elegant way of setting arraycolsep and the newline

```
\\[-5.15pt]
```

automatically to the correct value? I want the boxes to be as close as possible, vertically and horizontally.

Comment: 2\frulewidth+2\frulesep

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it), and you can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Sorry it is `2\fboxrule+2\fboxsep`

Comment: @Heiko: Your answer post created a new unregistered account (with the same name and icon). I merged both together now and moved your post to the question. Please consider to register your account to avoid such issues. Thanks.

Comment: I'd like to thank everyone for these most helpful suggestions! I'm still not used to this editor here, but at least now I'm registered ;)

Comment: @Heiko: Thanks for registering. I merged your old unregistered account with the new registered one. Please note that this site doesn't use a forum thread style but a question and answer style. Please only post solutions of the asked question as an answer post. You can add comments or edit the question to provide feedback. Instead of posting "thank you" posts simply up-vote useful answers and accept the most correct one. You couldn't do this before because the accounts weren't connected, but it should work now. Note that we prefer to not have greetings and signatures in the posts. Thanks!

Comment: @Heiko: I've edited my answer adding an alternative approach to the request in your update using `TikZ`.

Answer (score 5):

You are not taking into account `\fboxsep` (the separation between the framed box and its contents; default value: `3pt`) and the "thickness" of the rules used (`\fboxrule`: `0.4pt`, by default). If you set `\fboxsep` to `0pt`, then the box on the right will have a total height of `2cm+0.4pt` while the two stacked boxes on the left will have a total height of `1cm+1cm+(4*0.2pt)=2cm+0.8pt` (if the middle horizontal rules don't overlap, but are immediately next to each other) or `1cm+1cm+(3*0.2pt)=2cm+0.6pt` (if the middle horizontal rules overlap).

EDIT: by the way, instead of using `$$...$$` for displayed math, you should use `\[...\]`.

EDIT2: although I think that sometimes `TikZ` is overused, in this particular case I think that it would be sensible to give it a try (it facilitates the exact placement of the colored boxes):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\def\MyUnit{ex}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1\MyUnit,y=1\MyUnit]

\def\MyBox#1#2#3#4{\node[draw,fill=#1,minimum width=#2\MyUnit,minimum height=#2\MyUnit,align=center] at (#4) {#3};}

\matrix [matrix of nodes,left delimiter=(,right delimiter=)]
{
  \MyBox{yellow}{4}{A}{0,0}
  \MyBox{green}{4}{B}{4,0}
  \MyBox{blue}{4}{C}{4,-4}
  \MyBox{red}{8}{D}{10,-2}\\
};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Do not use the Tex primatives `\vbox` and `\hbox` in directly in latex, because they are not color "save". Use the latex equavalents `\parbox`, `\makebox`, and `minipage`.

The code below gives you a ruled box with required outer dimension (including the rule width and separation)

> EDIT:

Rather use the picture environment to add your boxes, then you have more control

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength\mylenA
\newlength\mylenB

\newcommand\mybox[4][t]{%
    \setlength\mylenA{#3\unitlength-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}%
    \setlength\mylenB{#3\unitlength-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}%
    \fcolorbox{black}{#2}{\parbox[#1][\mylenA][c]{\mylenB}{\centering #4}}}

\begin{document}

\setlength\unitlength{1ex}
$\left(
\begin{picture}(16,5)
    \put(0, 2){\mybox[c]{yellow}{4}{A}}
    \put(4, 2){\mybox[c]{green}{4}{B}}
    \put(4,-2){\mybox[c]{blue}{4}{C}}
    \put(8, 0){\mybox[c]{red}{8}{D}}
\end{picture}
\right)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by [[because they are not color "save"]]?